# return an object once the callback is completed

Tags: javascript, extjs

When this function is called, I would like that the function waits for the callback to finish before returning the object `r`

```
    function getWmsLayers(oneServerState){
            reader = new GeoExt.data.WMSCapabilitiesReader();;
            var serverLayers = new Array();
            var store = new GeoExt.data.WMSCapabilitiesStore({
                    url: OpenLayers.ProxyHost + oneServerState.serverUrl,
                    reader: reader
            });
            var isCallBackCompleted = false;
            store.load({
                    callback: function (r) {
                            return r;
                    }
            });
            //Do something ??
            return r;
    };


    layers = getWMSLayers(oneServerState);
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: When there's a callback, it's there for a reason. Instead of returning the response to your code, you need to bring your code to the response.

Comment: You are supposed to call back, not respond. Similar to "ask me later"...

Comment: @SLaks : so I must put the rest of my code inside the `callback` parameter ? This is a realy ugly OO aproach... :(

Comment: It's not an ugly OO approach. It's actually very elegant (once you are used to it). Like caviar. :)

Comment: @FrancoisValiquette you might want to check out [promises](http://www.slideshare.net/domenicdenicola/callbacks-promises-and-coroutines-oh-my-the-evolution-of-asynchronicity-in-javascript), they provide ways to clean up the mess :)

Comment: @FrancoisValiquette: No, put the rest of your code in a function, and pass the function as a second argument to `getWMSLayers()`, then invoke the function inside the callback, passing it the response, or just simply assign the function *as* the value of `callback:`. ...and none of this has to do with OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to w8 for layers to be load. like this:

```
    function getWmsLayers(oneServerState, fnCallback){
            reader = new GeoExt.data.WMSCapabilitiesReader();;
            var serverLayers = new Array();
            var store = new GeoExt.data.WMSCapabilitiesStore({
                    url: OpenLayers.ProxyHost + oneServerState.serverUrl,
                    reader: reader
            });
            var isCallBackCompleted = false;
            store.load({
                    callback: function (r) {
                        fnCallback(r);
                    }
            });
    };
```

And then call this function with this:

```
    getWmsLayers(serverstate, function ( l ) {
       layers = l;
       nextFunctiontoContinueProgressing();
    });
```

This is how you can build up a callback chain to complete your request.

Answer (score 2):

You can't wait for an async call to finish. That's essentially the definition of an async call!. The best you can do is split up your calling logic. So instead of this:

```
stuff();
result = doAsyncCall(); // WILL NOT WORK!
moreStuff(result);
```

use a callback like this:

```
stuff();
var callback = function (result) { moreStuff(result); };
doAsyncCall(callback);
```